# How to prevent navigation to UIViewController checking a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've a button that show a view controller (ViewControllerIncluirItem). But, I need check a condition before navigate, I try check this inside func `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`. But, the navigation ocurrs for any way. I did tried this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "SegueToVcIncluirItem" {

            if pricelist != nil {
                print("pricelist ok")              
            } else {
                print("selecione pricelist")
                return // Here I want prevent.
            }

            let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let childVc = nav.topViewController as! ViewControllerIncluirItem
            childVc.strTeste = "testado com sucesso"
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, you is wrong! This question is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check your condition in the method [shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue)

Your code should look like this:

```
    func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String,
                            sender: Any?) -> Bool{

        if identifier == "SegueToVcIncluirItem" {
           return pricelist != nil
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: how I put the parameters for the next view controller?

Comment: The `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` determines if the segue should be performed, You still can set parameters to your destination viewController in the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: This solves my problem. Just change your code, the var `segue` not existis in this method. :)

Comment: Fixed thanks, good catch

Answer (score 0):

`func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` is called when you ask that to be called. You must be using this :

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: nil)
```

The condition you are putting in `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, you should put in before the call. So it should be :

```
if pricelist != nil {
    print("pricelist ok")   
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "", sender: nil) 
} else {
    print("selecione pricelist")
}
```

Now your prepare function should look very simple :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let childVc = nav.topViewController as! ViewControllerIncluirItem
        childVc.strTeste = "testado com sucesso"
}
```

Comment: Where I write `self.performSegue` ?

Comment: On button click event.

Comment: I using direct from storyboard the navigation.

Comment: You can create an IBAction for button.

Comment: This way not works, because my navigationbar fades.

Comment: How can the navigation fade ? There is no code written which makes the fading effect.

Comment: "How can the navigation fad ? " If you reply this, reply my question.

Comment: Is the destination VC (nav controller's top controller) called after execution of func prepare ?

Comment: Your answer is very confused.

Comment: I dont think @Nitish answer is confusing. Simply instead of Pushing on buttons click you can create an IBAction and there you can put your check. Whether you have to navigate or not.

Comment: Alright. Let's go from top to bottom. 1. Create IBAction for button and connect that in the storyboard. 2. Write the conditional code I have written in the answer in that IBAction. 3. Write prepare function as I have mentioned.

Comment: Thak you for help, but the answer above solves my problem.